# I need help removing a layer of mesh going through my complex tunnel

Tags: mesh

I started using blender this summer, and I got a mesh with these weird bridges where it should be hollow. This is supposed to be a hollow tunnel, but as you can see in the pictures below there is a layer of mesh in the middle of the tunnel following the path. I'm thanful for any suggestions or tips on how to get rid of the mesh passing the middle! This is all rendered from a point cloud, and I haven't used any modifiers yet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: do you have modifiers on the object ? You generated the mesh in some way, we can't help you if you don't tell us how

Comment: yes okay it's a point cloud scanned by a drone :). My guess is that this problem in the mesh is where the drone flew through the tunnel, because under it the normals are also flipped the other way around.